# UIVisualEffectView is erroneously also influenced by layers above it

Tags: swift, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

In my app, I want a CTA button to be displayed under the ads. This is located on a UIVisualEffectView for better readability.

In principle, it already works as I would like, but I have noticed a strange behavior when the EffectView scrolled under the navigation bar.

This changes slowly more and more the color to the Nav-Bar color, although this lies in a layer above. Why is this happening? How can I make sure that only the underlying colors are used?

Here is an example video:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/liwyys9te3et8ns/UIVisualEffectView_Example_1.mp4?dl=0

Edit:

Don’t think this is relevant, but this is the code:

```
let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: colorMode == .light ? .light : .dark)
blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
ctaBackground?.addSubview(blurEffectView!)
self.addSubview(ctaBackground!)
```

Comment: Did you figure out the cause and solution? Also finding the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the frame.

`blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds`.

Otherwise, more code would help.
Can't tell what is `ctaBackground`. Is it whole screen or just the background of that small CTA.

Furthermore, you should not force unwrap.

```
let bacgroundView = UIView()
addSubview(backgroundView)
ctaBackground = backgroundView
```